# PHP pdf generator query

Tags: php, pdf, generator

Can anyone please suggest me which php based pdf generator supoorts svg,background-image(css) and table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FPDF or tcpdf seem to be the most popular choices. I use FPDF personally and have created some very dynamic PDF's from MySQL tables.

Answer (score 1):

I used `mPDF` that is very capable of this - even You can create an `HTML` with `CSS` and **images** and then let `mPDF` to generate `PDF` from the source `HTML`.

Comment: I have used this once a few weeks ago and it's simply nice.

Answer (score 0):

You should try http://www.tcpdf.org